# get entire past mqtt message queue?

Tags: mqtt

When in QOS 1 & 2 it replays all past messages. Is there a way in standard implementations to receive the entire past queue (as array) when becoming live again? (Of course only subscribed ones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a client has subscribed to a topic at QOS 1 or 2 and then disconnects. If when that client reconnects with the same client id and with the clean session flag set to false, the broker should replay any missed messages.

The broker should not replay any messages that had already been sent during the first connected period (with the possible exception of any QOS 1 messages that may have been in flight at the time of the disconnect)

Comment: thanks, not really what i was looking for. I need all messages which are replayed as simple array instead of waiting for an unspecified amount messages....

Comment: That would be out of spec, so no broker is going to do it as standard

Comment: ok, I see. I don't know why but having no access to all messages seems pretty lame. actually i don't know even know how to optimize now my app for duplicates etc...

Comment: The protocol was designed to be as light as possible, anything else goes on the payload, such as message  id's so you can do deduplication

Comment: yup, i just changed the sources and got the gains i wanted ;-) If you would update you answer for  "not possible", I would accept it :-) thanks!

Comment: I know a long time has passed but can you explain to me what you did? I have a problem that for the client who receives the message it takes too long to execute it and newer messages start to add up and I would like to use just the latest message.